# Filtering dropdown queryset in Django view

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter my queryset for my form dropdown

form.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [  'GTIN','name','style1','style2','style3','size','dimension','color','UOM','description','keywords', 'defaultPrice' ,'customerdiscount']
```

view.py

```
@login_required
def product_edit(request,pk,uri):
    uri = _get_redirect_url(request, uri)
    post = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save(commit=False)
            product.creation_time = timezone.now()
            product.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, product.name + "-SUCCESS Object saved sucssefully")
            return redirect(uri)
    else:
        form = ProductForm(instance=post)
        form.UOM.queryset = UOM.objects.filter(id=pk)

    material = post.material   
    return render(request, 'item/product/product_edit.html', {'form': form, 'material':material })
```

I don't know if my approach is correct or no (I added this line  form.UOM.queryset = UOM.objects.filter(id=pk)  to my working view  )

but now I am getting an error : `'ProductForm' object has no attribute 'UOM'`

I clearly see that this form does have attribute UOM. What could be the problem? As well will this approach work to filter data from my dropdown data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
form.fields['UOM'].queryset = UOM.objects.filter(id=pk)
```